# Select from Tarantool by secondary index with sort by another field and limit/offset

Tags: lua, tarantool, nosql

I have some space **top** with fields:
 **-id**,
**-status**,
**-rating**

I have two indexes for space **top**:

```
--primary  
box.space.top:create_index('primary', { type = 'TREE', unique = true, parts = { 1, 'NUM' } })
--status
box.space.top:create_index('status', { type = 'TREE', unique = false, parts = { 2, 'NUM' } })
```

I can select by **id** or **status**

```
--select by id 
space.top.index.primary:select(someId) 
--select by status with limit/offset 
space.top.index.status:select({someStatus}, {iterator = box.index.EQ, offset = 0, limit = 20})
```

Sometimes i need select by **status** with ordering by **rating**.
What is the best way? Create another index with parts **status**, **rating** and make some tricky query if it`s possible? Or continue select by **status** and make sort by **rating** in Lua procedure?
Thanks!

**UPD:**
Thanks, Kostya!
I modified index **status** like this:

```
box.space.top:create_index('status_rating', { type = 'TREE', unique = false, parts = { 2, 'NUM', 3 'NUM' } })
```

And now i can query:

```
local active_status = 1 
local limit = 20 
local offset = 0
box.space.top.index.status_rating:select({active_status}, {iterator = box.index.LE, offset=offset, limit=limit})
```

Great!

Comment: Good advise requires  more information about your data.

What average number of rows each status has?

Will you read all pages or only first one?

Comment: The average number of rows is about 2000 - 3000 units. I`m going to use limit/offset options for paginations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't make sense to create the third index, if you need to order by rating, just include it into the second index as the second part, and use GE/GT iterator, the data will come out ordered. This is an in-memory database, adding more parts to an index doesn't use up more memory, only slows down insertion a bit.

Comment: It works! Kostya`s solution in my implementation is in **UPD** question`s section

Answer (score 1):

Call with GE/LE iterator and partial index may work **not as expected** than there is no matching tuples or limit is too high.

Suppose, we have following tuples (status, rating):

```
{ 1, 1 }
{ 3, 1 }
{ 3, 2 }
```

Than call

```
box.space.top.index.status_rating:select({2}, {iterator = box.index.GE, limit=1})
```

will return tuple  {3, 1}  as it greater than {2}

And call

```
box.space.top.index.status_rating:select({1}, {iterator = box.index.GE, limit=2})
```

will return two tuples {1, 1}, {3, 1}

In both case tuple {3, 1} may be **not expected**